# How to iterate through the list reversly?

Tags: jquery

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24052824/how-can-i-add-numbers-increasing-with-start-point-from-classname) today and curiously made my own concept(or may be as of the OP concept of that question) but stucked here that how can I iterate over the list after the active class and start again from beginning. Let's make me clear from the following html:

```
<ul>
  <li name="6">one</li>
  <li name="1" class="active">two</li>
  <li name="2">three</li>
  <li name="3">four</li>
  <li name="4">five</li>
  <li name="5">six</li>
</ul>
```

Now, if the active class is in second last li, then look like this:

```
<ul>
  <li name="3">one</li>
  <li name="4">two</li>
  <li name="5">three</li>
  <li name="6">four</li>
  <li name="1" class="active">five</li>
  <li name="2">six</li>
</ul>
```

For longer list this would look like this:

```
<ul>
  <li name="3">one</li>
  <li name="4">two</li>
  <li name="5">three</li>
  <li name="6">four</li>
  <li name="1" class="active">five</li>
  <li name="2">six</li>
  <li name="3">seven</li>
  <li name="4">eight</li>
  <li name="5">nine</li>
  <li name="6">ten</li>
  <li name="1">eleven</li>
  <li name="2">tweleve</li>
</ul>
```

**I mean I wanted to do like this:**

- From active class it should start from 1 and **increase** by 1 for next
  sibling
- From active class it should start from 1 and **decrease** by 1 for
  previous sibling (meaning that 6, 5, 4...)

What I've done is:

```
$('li').attr('name',function(i){
  i += 5
    return i % 6 + 1;
});
```

But it will just results fine if the active class is in second list. So how should I do if I don't know where the active class would be?

Comment: I don't think this is the duplicate question that you provide, it's about backwards and forwards, the condition is both....

Comment: you want to run a infinite loop switching something like this -> for(li = 1 ; li < li.length ; li++); ?

Comment: Use a selector to get everything `:after` the attribute you want. Then select again with `:before`.

Comment: @Jonno_FTW a jsfiddle please.

Comment: Use `.nextAll()` and `prevAll()`. Check **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6mw4K/)** Is this what you want?

Comment: @niko like this demo http://jsfiddle.net/zb47t/2/

Comment: So you don't actually want to iterate through the list in reverse? You want to iterate through from `activated` and then again from `activated`. `var i = 1;$('li.active').nextAll().each(function(){$(this).attr('name',i++%6);});$('li.active').prevAll().each(function(){$(this).attr('name',i++%6);};`.

Comment: @shaunakde I wanted to know specially iterating backwards and forwards simultaneiously. Anyway thank you.

Comment: I do have a question, why 6?

Comment: iteration ends at 6. and continue from 1 again.

Comment: should always it be 6? you should have specify that...

Comment: did you check the list I show.

Comment: yes, I was just wondering why 6..

Comment: no, there's no reason you could use any stop value like 10.

Comment: (OT) Is `name` a valid `LI` attribute? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's a good way to do it... ;)

```
var stopvalue = 6;
var activeindex = $('li.active').index() % stopvalue ;
$('ul>li').attr('name', function (i) {
    return (i + (stopvalue - activeindex)) % stopvalue  + 1;
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/UKNr6/)

Comment: @C-link, I'm sorry but I don't know how to explain it... What I did was look for the relationship of the needed output number and the given numbers. I come up with that. It took me time, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6mw4K/4/)** , using **[.nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/)**
 and **[.prevAll()](http://api.jquery.com/prevall/)**

```
var activeVal = $( "li.active" ).attr('name');

$( "li.active" ).nextAll().each(function(i){
        $(this).attr('name',function(){
        return i + parseInt(activeVal) + 1;
    });    
}).end().prevAll().each(function(i){
    $(this).attr('name',function(){
        return i +parseInt(activeVal)+1;
    });    
});
```

---

**Comments:**

- First Loop - `.nextAll()`. Iterate form next till last element.
- Second Loop - `.prevAll()`. Iterate from previous to the first.

To check the iterations verify this in console :

```
$('li').each(function(){
   console.log($(this).attr('name')); 
});
```

---

Comment: @Reigel, chaining `.prevAll()` causes it to check `prevAll()` of the last element.